# creating a patch using gitonomy gitlib library

Tags: php, git

I am using Gitonomy libray Git lib to manipulate Git repository through php. I am to create patch file from a repository and there is no function for creating, reverting and applying patch files. There is a function named 'run' that can run git commands directly but they are ended up in exceptions. May be I am passing wrong arguments to the function. Can any one help me out in creating a patch files through Gitonomy Git lib Library. Following is the link of the library.

https://github.com/gitonomy/gitlib

Thanks and Regards,
Furqan Ahmed.

Comment: You can see an example on how to use run at https://github.com/gitonomy/gitlib/issues/11#issuecomment-12199559. Or in https://github.com/gitonomy/gitlib/pull/50/files#diff-bf5d6e84db0531e94e0540ea810e8c39R37. How are you using run? What exception do you get?

Comment: I have 3 commits on my repository and I need to create a patch for the commits so that I can email it to admin to apply the patch over the remote repository. The command that I am using in the git bash is as follows:

git format-patch -3 HEAD --stdout > patches/third.patch


$repository = new Repository("/vagrant/project/devrepo/remote");

$repository->run('format-patch', array('-3', 'HEAD', '--stdout', 'devrepo/remote/master/project/patches/fix_empty_poster.patch'));

Can you please guide me where i am going wrong with the arguments in the array?????.


Thaks and Regards,

Furqan Ahmed.

Comment: Update,

after running the function reppository->run (as described above) I am getting the following error : 


Error while running git command:
'git' '--git-dir' '/vagrant/project/devrepo/remote/.git' '--work-tree' '/vagrant/project/devrepo/remote' 'format-patch' 'devrepo/remote/master/project/patches/fix_empty_poster.patch' '--stdout' '-3' 'HEAD'

fatal: ambiguous argument 'devrepo/remote/master/project/patches/fix_empty_poster.patch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: I have made it working, let me share it with you. The path of the patch file that I am giving as an argument should be replaced with 'origin/master' and it will return the patch as a string and then we have to create a file with the content and save to a location. 

Anyways, thanks for you help.

Comment: Ok, I have posted an answer for more visibility. Is the code I have copied (where I replaced the path with `origin/master`) correct?

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned in the comments as examples of how to use `run`:

- [issues/11](https://github.com/gitonomy/gitlib/issues/11#issuecomment-12199559)
- [patch PR 50](https://github.com/gitonomy/gitlib/pull/50/files#diff-bf5d6e84db0531e94e0540ea810e8c39R37)

The [OP Furqan Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924260/furqan-ahmed) adds

> The path of the patch file that I am giving as an argument should be replaced with '`origin/master`' and it will return the patch as a string and then we have to create a file with the content and save to a location.

```
git format-patch -3 HEAD --stdout > patches/third.patch 
$repository = new Repository("/vagrant/project/devrepo/remote"); 
$repository->run('format-patch', array('-3', 'HEAD', '--stdout', 'origin/master/project/patches/fix_empty_poster.patch'));
```

Comment: If you want the patch as a string this should be enough: `$output = $repository->run('format-patch', array('-3', 'HEAD', '--stdout')); file_put_contents('path/to/file.patch', $output);